# Facebook likes and shares for a URL differ when embedded on website and when posted on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

When i embed facebook like and share button on website it is linked to URL of that page.
But when i post this url on facebook its likes and shares start with 0
How to get same likes and shares for same URL after posting it on facebook???

Comment: First guess is that you're posting a slightly different URL. And how do you check the like and share counts?

Comment: You can check this URL: [link]http://www.ambitionme.com/Module/xupeqm/Quiz.php where two people liked this and when i post this URL on facebook no. of likes start with 0. I want likes from website also. Is there any other way to do it?? I'm just pasting like button code provided by facebook and initializing it with my fb app ID. Thanks in advance

Comment: I fetch no. of likes from following url in JSON format [link](http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.ambitionme.com/Module/xupeqm/Quiz.php)

Comment: Strange, querying the `link_stat` table shows even different results: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20url%2C%20like_count%2C%20comment_count%2C%20share_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ambitionme.com%2FModule%2Fxupeqm%2FQuiz.php%22